# Exception happens when using RenderScript to create a blur image

Tags: android, renderscript

I want to create a blur image by using RenderScript but it crashes when the `RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);` is called.

Here is the error log:

**android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: RenderScript code cache directory uninitialized**

```
' android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: RenderScript code cache directory uninitialized.
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6097)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:925)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:813)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: RenderScript code cache directory uninitialized.
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.renderscript.RenderScript.getCachePath(RenderScript.java:1392)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.renderscript.RenderScript.internalCreate(RenderScript.java:1430)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1526)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1485)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1459)
01-16 16:28:54.667 25502 25502 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1446)'
```

Does anyone have any solutions ?

Thanks

Comment: Now I test my application and find it works well in Android 6 but crash in Android 7, Did anyone have ever had the same problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [`android support v8 renderscipt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/package-summary.html) library to avoid some system problems.